# Ruby on Rails 1.23 application on Ruby 1.87 on FreeBSD keeps crashing on startup (fcgi)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, freebsd, lighttpd

After a recent server switch I am having troubles getting a Ruby on Rails app with legacy (1.8) code up and running. I am testing it by running /www/application/public/dispatch.fcgi

**Enviroment**

- Freebsd 10.0
- Ruby 1.8.7 via RVM
- ruby19-gems-1.8.29
- Lighttpd-1.4.35_2

**List of installed gems**

```
actionmailer (1.3.3)
actionpack (1.13.3)
actionwebservice (1.2.3)
activerecord (1.15.3)
activesupport (1.4.2)
bundler (1.6.3)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
fcgi (0.9.2.1)
gem-wrappers (1.2.5)
rails (1.2.3)
rake (10.1.1)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
```

**fastcgi.crash.log**

```
[07/Jul/2014:17:01:45 :: 60555] starting
[07/Jul/2014:17:01:45 :: 60555] Dispatcher failed to catch: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.split (NoMethodError)
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/cgi.rb:903:in `parse'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/actionpack-1.13.3/lib/action_controller/cgi_ext/raw_post_data_fix.rb:45:in `initialize_query'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/cgi.rb:2286:in `initialize'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/fcgi-0.9.2.1/lib/fcgi.rb:627:in `new'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/fcgi-0.9.2.1/lib/fcgi.rb:627:in `each_cgi'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-1.2.3/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:141:in `process_each_request!'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-1.2.3/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:55:in `process!'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-1.2.3/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:25:in `process!'
  /www/checkout/public/dispatch.fcgi:24
almost killed by this error
[07/Jul/2014:17:01:45 :: 60555] Dispatcher failed to catch: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.split (NoMethodError)
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/cgi.rb:903:in `parse'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/actionpack-1.13.3/lib/action_controller/cgi_ext/raw_post_data_fix.rb:45:in `initialize_query'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/cgi.rb:2286:in `initialize'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/fcgi-0.9.2.1/lib/fcgi.rb:627:in `new'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/fcgi-0.9.2.1/lib/fcgi.rb:627:in `each_cgi'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-1.2.3/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:141:in `process_each_request!'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-1.2.3/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:55:in `process!'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-1.2.3/lib/fcgi_handler.rb:25:in `process!'
  /www/checkout/public/dispatch.fcgi:24
killed by this error
```

**Contents of dispatch.fcgi**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby18
#
# You may specify the path to the FastCGI crash log (a log of unhandled
# exceptions which forced the FastCGI instance to exit, great for debugging)
# and the number of requests to process before running garbage collection.
#
# By default, the FastCGI crash log is RAILS_ROOT/log/fastcgi.crash.log
# and the GC period is nil (turned off).  A reasonable number of requests
# could range from 10-100 depending on the memory footprint of your app.
#
# Example:
#   # Default log path, normal GC behavior.
#   RailsFCGIHandler.process!
#
#   # Default log path, 50 requests between GC.
#   RailsFCGIHandler.process! nil, 50
#
#   # Custom log path, normal GC behavior.
#   RailsFCGIHandler.process! '/var/log/myapp_fcgi_crash.log'
#
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment"
require 'fcgi_handler'

RailsFCGIHandler.process!
```

Any ideas how this can be solved will be greatly appreciated. Please request more information in comments if need.

Comment: `rails (1.2.3)` :O why would you use that?

Comment: @TheChamp Pretty sure he's not writing this application from scratch. Believe it or not, some people have legacy applications to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect your problem is that ruby 1.8.7 is too new. Ruby only very recently adopted semantic versioning and 1.8.7 included a very significant number of changes to the standard library (it was in part intended as a bridge to ruby 1.9)

Ruby 1.8.7 was released in May 2008, over a year after rails 1.2.3 was released - the 1.2 branch was no longer being worked on at that point. It seems like rails 2.2 was the first version to support ruby 1.8.7 (this http://www.devalot.com/articles/2012/03/ror-compatibility has a table of ruby versions against rails version. In addition there are a number of ruby 1.8.7 related commits that weren't in earlier versions, although rails 2.1.2 seems to include most of the fixes)

Downgrading to ruby 1.8.6 should get you up and running.

You'll also need to be careful with gem versions, for example rake 10.x won't work with a version of rails that old. Unfortunately bundler didn't exist back then so some guesswork may be required to figure out the right versions.

Comment: Great, it seems like a plausible solution. However now I have issues compiling 1.8.6 so I cannot try it. Any ideas? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618720/cant-compile-install-ruby-1-8-6-with-rvm-error-running-rvm-make-b-j8

Comment: Rail 1.2.3 requires rake 0.7.2 which requires ruby 1.8.7 it seems.

Comment: I managed to install 1.8.6 with rails 1.2.3 but I still get the same error.

Comment: Are you just invoking public/dispatch.fcgi at the command prompt?

Comment: I don't think that will work - rails will expect the environment the web server would set up to be there eg REQUEST_URI). I'd try to get the app running under webrick first (ruby script/server)

Comment: Thanks @Frederick Cheung. It works fine webrick. I will run it like that for now since its not a public app. What could the issue be? Incompability with my version of the fcgi gem?

Comment: I don't think it's that, but dispatch.fcgi is supposed to be invoked by the apache fcgi module, which sets a bunch of environment variables for it. If you're just running it by hand then that environment won't exist

Answer (score 0):

My answer is to try actually running under ruby 1.9 and see if it works.  Unlike 1.9 -> 2.0 when the new hash syntax was introduced and new code that used the syntax woudn't work under the old version, for 1.8 -> 1.9 there's a reasonable chance that the vast majority of the code will work as is.

Most folks are/have moved to Ruby 2.x from 1.9 so getting to 1.9 would be the minimum version I would try and troubleshoot on.  Trying to get help with 1.8 code will be hard (and/or expensive and time-consuming and certainly frustrating).

Other:  Starting it with `running /www/application/public/dispatch.fcgi` seems unusual.
I've always started my rails servers locally with `rails server` (or `script/rails server` for older rails versions like yours) in the project root.

Comment: Ruby 1.9 broke lots of code/gems because of the new encoding system - way more disruptive in my experience than ruby 1.9 to 2.0

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you know what the error is related to? Is it a programing issue or issue with the Ruby installation?