# Can't compile / install Ruby 1.8.6 with RVM (Error running '__rvm_make -B -j8')

Tags: ruby, rvm, freebsd

I am having issues compiling Ruby 1.8.6 using RVM on FreeBSD 10. How can I solve this?

**Commands run:**

- rvm remove 1.8.6 (to make sure we start clean)
- rvm autolibs enable
- rvm install 1.8.6 --with-gcc=clang

**Install log and error given:**

```
[root@sensation ~]# rvm install 1.8.6 --with-gcc=clang
Checking requirements for freebsd.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.8.6-p420 - #downloading ruby-1.8.6-p420, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.8.6-p420 - #extracting ruby-1.8.6-p420 to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.8.6-p420....
ruby-1.8.6-p420 - #applying patch /usr/local/rvm/patches/ruby/1.8.6/openssl-1.0.patch...........
ruby-1.8.6-p420 - #applying patch /usr/local/rvm/patches/ruby/1.8.6/stdout-rouge-fix.patch..
ruby-1.8.6-p420 - #applying patch /usr/local/rvm/patches/ruby/1.8.6/no_sslv2.diff..
ruby-1.8.6-p420 - #applying patch /usr/local/rvm/patches/ruby/1.8.6/syck.patch..
ruby-1.8.6-p420 - #configuring............................
ruby-1.8.6-p420 - #post-configuration.
ruby-1.8.6-p420 - #compiling.........................
Error running '__rvm_make -B -j8',
showing last 15 lines of /usr/local/rvm/log/1404762617_ruby-1.8.6-p420/make.log
clang -O3 -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -DRUBY_EXPORT -I. -I.   -c util.c
clang -O3 -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -DRUBY_EXPORT -I. -I.   -c variable.c
clang -O3 -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -DRUBY_EXPORT -I. -I.   -c version.c
clang -O3 -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -DRUBY_EXPORT -I. -I.   -c dmyext.c
ar rcu libruby-static.a array.o  bignum.o  class.o  compar.o  dir.o  dln.o  enum.o  error.o  eval.o  file.o  gc.o  hash.o  inits.o  io.o  marshal.o  math.o  numeric.o  object.o  pack.o  parse.o  process.o  prec.o  random.o  range.o  re.o  regex.o  ruby.o  signal.o  sprintf.o  st.o  string.o  struct.o  time.o  util.o  variable.o  version.o   dmyext.o
clang -O3 -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -DRUBY_EXPORT -I. -I.   -c main.c
clang -O3 -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -DRUBY_EXPORT -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -rdynamic   main.o  libruby-static.a -lrt -lcrypt -lm   -o miniruby
./lib/fileutils.rb:1471: uninitialized constant OPT_TABLE (NameError)
        from ./mkconfig.rb:10:in `require'
        from ./mkconfig.rb:10
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.8.6-p420
++ return 1
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Same error when using cc (rvm install 1.8.6):

```
Error running '__rvm_make -B -j8',
showing last 15 lines of /usr/local/rvm/log/1404763496_ruby-1.8.6-p420/make.log
cc -O3 -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -DRUBY_EXPORT -I. -I.   -c util.c
cc -O3 -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -DRUBY_EXPORT -I. -I.   -c variable.c
cc -O3 -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -DRUBY_EXPORT -I. -I.   -c version.c
cc -O3 -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -DRUBY_EXPORT -I. -I.   -c dmyext.c
ar rcu libruby-static.a array.o  bignum.o  class.o  compar.o  dir.o  dln.o  enum.o  error.o  eval.o  file.o  gc.o  hash.o  inits.o  io.o  marshal.o  math.o  numeric.o  object.o  pack.o  parse.o  process.o  prec.o  random.o  range.o  re.o  regex.o  ruby.o  signal.o  sprintf.o  st.o  string.o  struct.o  time.o  util.o  variable.o  version.o   dmyext.o
cc -O3 -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -DRUBY_EXPORT -I. -I.   -c main.c
cc -O3 -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -DRUBY_EXPORT -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -rdynamic   main.o  libruby-static.a -lrt -lcrypt -lm   -o miniruby
./lib/fileutils.rb:1471: uninitialized constant OPT_TABLE (NameError)
        from ./mkconfig.rb:10:in `require'
        from ./mkconfig.rb:10
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.8.6-p420
++ return 1
```

Comment: 1.8.6 predates clang by some years - try another compiler?

Comment: Which one do you suggest?

Comment: Well back in the days of 1.8.6 gcc was the default.

Comment: It seems I get the same error with gcc, I added the log.

Answer (score 1):

I installed gcc47 via `pkg install gcc`and now it worked when I ran

`rvm install 1.8.6 --with-gcc=gcc47`.